# Send wall message to multiple users using facebook javascript sdk

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk

I'm trying to send from one site to post a message on a wall of multiple users using the facebook js sdk.

I have an issue, it seems we cannot put multiple 'to' recipients in the js code provided.
Is there any solution please?

The code I have:

```
                $(document).ready(function () {
                $('form').bind('submit', function () {

                    FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
                        if (response.status === 'connected') {
                            var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
                            var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
                        }
                    });

                    var chkArray = [];
                    $(".fb_friend :checked").each(function () {

                        FB.ui({
                            method: 'feed',
                            name: 'Event On GiFolio !',
                            link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/dialogs/',
                            picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
                            caption: '',
                            description: 'Click on the link to join my event on GiFolio !',
                            to: $(this).val()
                        }, function(response){
                            console.log(response);
                        });
                    });


                    return false;
                });
            });
```

Img: [image]

Comment: That is not possible using the Feed dialog. It is one of Facebook’s measures against spam. Only the old version of the share dialog allows the user to select multiple recipients.

Comment: The old version you mean the old api or is there another way?

Comment: Not sure if that is even available any more – most sites I’ve seen seem to have moved to the new version recently.

Comment: Ok. Do you have any link where I can see how to do what I want without using the feed dialog maybe?